# Seaborn indices issue

Tags: python

I am writing a Machine Learning application and everything is working fine. In the end I decided to just use seaborn to do some quick visualization and now I am running into problems. My code is the following:

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.lmplot(x='NewCity',y='Employees',data=New_Data, hue='NewDesc', palette='coolwarm')
```

But when I run it I am getting the following error:
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Here is a simple dataset example
ID  Company Name  Location  Employees  NewDesc
1   XYZ            China     100000      1
2   ABC            USA       555555      0

The data actually contained a "description" column which I transformed so that it labels into categories of 1 or 0. Then I added that new column as NewDesc and dropped the "description" column

Not sure what's going on or why it's showing this error.

Comment: and newDesc is really an integer (`1`), not a string with value `"1"`?

Comment: Ahh!! I will double-check that. I used LabelEncoder to transform the original column into numbered values. So it might be a string